# What is the correct way to check if an address is zero?

Tags: solidity

I remember reading that the correct way to check if an address is `0x0` or not is  `_addr == address(0)` and not `_addr == 0`. However, I'm unable to find any difference between the two when I run the following:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract Test {
    bool public isResult1 = false;
    bool public isResult2 = false;

    function isAddressZero1(address _addr) public {
        isResult1 = (_addr == address(0));
    }

    function isAddressZero2(address _addr) public {
        isResult2 = (_addr == 0);
    }
}
```

Is there a known issue with `_addr == 0` or is the explicit typecasting just to be safe?

Comment: Any of those are fine. I usually do `_addr != 0x0` to make it easily identifiable in code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These should be completely equivalent. I think some people may prefer `0x0` or `address(0)` or `address(0x0)` as some sort of convention (to make it a little clearer what kind of `0` you mean), but they all should compile to the same thing.

Solidity Version 0.5.0 onwards, you cannot compare directly with 0 or 0x0 or "0" or "0x0". Since these types are not treated as address.

Comment: In Solidity version 0.5.0 ; comparing with integer 0 is not allowed anymore.

Answer (score 6):

In solidity 0.5 this is the correct way to compare addresses

```
require(address(_registry) != address(0));
```

Comment: Any source to assert this is the correct way ?

Comment: For instance these snippets from the solidity documentation? https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.3/solidity-by-example.html?highlight=address(0)