# What is the "correct" way to check if an address is zero?

Tags: addresses, require

A similar question was asked here: [What is the correct way to check if an address is zero?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/34663/what-is-the-correct-way-to-check-if-an-address-is-zero) but it was back in 2017.

What's the purpose of `require(account != address(0));` and is it still relevant? I haven't seen any updated documentation around it for best practices

Answer (score 0):

```
require(account != address(0x0))
```